# What happen when UNION parent rdd and child rdd before action?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, rdd

Suppose I have some rdd has lineage like this:

rdd0 -> rdd1 -> rdd2 -> rdd3 -> rdd4

What happen when I do rdd1.union(rdd2).union(rdd3).union(rdd4).collect()? Will spark do the re-computation of transformation from rdd0 to rdd3 when calculating rdd4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`union` is a transformation, so when you do `val x = a union(b)`, it adds a new element to the lineage which is referred to by the identifier `x`. Nothing is really computed at this point. Think of it like a blue print to which elements are added. When an action is called on `x`, this blue print executes, starting from the first element that was added.

Now, in your case, when you do `rdd1.union(rdd2).union(rdd3).union(rdd4).collect()`, you basically added 3 elements to your blue print (the resultant of `rdd1` and `rdd2`, union of `rdd3` with previous resultant and union of `rdd4` with previous resultant). Now the blueprint finally executes from start when you call `collect()` on this finally resultant.

In case you are using `rdd1` for a lot of operations, its best to cache/ persist it otherwise it will re-compute.

Let me know if this helped, Cheers.

Comment: Thanks! I understand union will only be executed when call some action. Actually what I'm concerned is that if it is necessary to cache my rdd1 or not. Do you mean when perform the action it will calculate the (rdd0 -> rdd1) + (rdd0 -> rdd1 -> rdd2 ) + (rdd0 -> rdd1 -> rdd2 -> rdd3) + ..... or it can automatically optimize as (rdd0 -> rdd1) + (rdd1 -> rdd2 ) + ( rdd2 -> rdd3) + ..?

Comment: yes in that case you will need to cache data. so, in case you are using rdd1 for a lot of operations, its best to cache/ persist it otherwise it will re-compute

Answer (score 0):

When you call the union, the spark will get a new RDD.This RDD has members ro keep its parent to calculate its dependence. The dependence is used to generate the DAG. DAG is used to generate the stage when action is called.